# Convert request SQL in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to convert this `request` below in Laravel Eloquent.

```
select * from revision
where fk_motorbike = NumberMoto
and start_time between time_start_training and time_stop_training 
or start_stop between time_start_training and time_stop_training
```

I am stuck after the second line...

```
$Revision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
->where('start_time', "<=", $time_start_training) ?
???
->first();
```

I am still a beginner in laravel.

Thank your for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing the two between condition are supposed to be inside parenthesis.

```php
$Revision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
    ->where(function($query) use($time_start_training, $time_stop_training) {
        $query->whereBetween('start_time', [$time_start_training, $time_stop_training])
            ->orWhereBetween('start_stop', [$time_start_training, $time_stop_training]);
    })
    ->first();
```